# is there any way to enable hibernation in a Windows 7 boot-to-vhd scenario?

Tags: windows-7, hibernate, boot-to-vhd

I use win7 boot-to-vhd on my laptop. Even though my laptop will go into sleep mode when I'm not using it, sometimes if I don't pull out the laptop for a day or two, the battery will drain anyways and when I turn it on I get the "Windows did not shut down properly" message.

I know why hibernation is disabled - but is there any way to enable it anyways?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Unless you have specific needs for using boot to VHD, I would recommend looking at virtualisation which can meet some of the same results.